# Kotlin why non-null assertion required despite null check

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to handle a retrofit response on Kotlin/Android:

```
if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                    val result = response.body().result
```

First I don't understand how the response can be successful and the body null. Anyways, if I add the null check I also get "Smart cast to 'xy' is impossible, because 'response.body()' is a complex expression" Add non-null asserted code (!!)
Actually to me those are two separate warnings, but why the null-Assertion request?

Comment: ```First I don't understand how the response can be successful and the body null```. Please check HTTP 204 code

Comment: @LeandroMaro Is the Javadoc incorrect? https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Response.java#L150

Comment: @Tenfour04 the javadoc doesn't say anything about the body being non-null, though. The body could be deserialized to null.

Comment: @Joffrey No, though I think it's ambiguous the way it's written. It seems to at least imply there is a value when it's `isSuccessful`, but maybe they consider `null` to be a valid "deserialized value".

Comment: Yeah I agree the doc is imprecise here. That's why I wouldn't personally rule out `null` as a possible value with so little information

Comment: @Tenfour04 I haven't said that Javadoc is incorrect, I'm saying that in restful services, 204 responses are successful responses within empty body that might lead to a null while deserialization. https://newbedev.com/rxjava2-retrofit2-handling-null-for-204-put-and-delete-requests

Comment: Still I think that as an API it shuold return success or error, and not a "partial" success that could actually be an "error". Now I need to add 100 checks in my code for the case the body is null, for the case the result is null, etc.

Comment: In addition to 204, [205 response documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.3.6) says "a server MUST NOT generate a payload in a 205 response". It would probably also be represented by `null` body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler can’t know that `body()` is guaranteed to return the same thing each time so it can’t smart-cast it to non-null. Also, it doesn’t know anything as complex as the fact that the body won’t be null if `isSuccessful` is true.

Since we know from the documentation of this library that it will always be the same, it’s safe to use `!!`. But you could alternatively copy the value to a local variable and work with that variable in your null check. Then you could be sure your code is safe even if you misinterpreted the documentation.

I don't really use Retrofit myself, but from a little bit of reading about it, I know that you can work with it more naturally in Kotlin by using suspend functions, and then you wouldn't have to work with callbacks and Response objects. So instead of creating a function that returns a `Call<MyData>`, followed by enqueuing the call, listening for success/failure, and then unwrapping the body if it's successful; instead you can mark the function as `suspend` and return `MyData` directly. Use try/catch or `runCatching` when making the function call, because it throws when not successful.

Comment: From the comment on your question above, be careful. Maybe there can be a successful response with null body. I think the documentation of `body()` could be clearer, so you might still want to do the null check. Instead, the `isSuccessful` check can probably be dropped because there won't be a `body()` if it's not successful.

Comment: I'm using it with suspend functions, that doesn't mean you won't need a Response Object, if you want to abstract the complexity of checking for all the possible null values and simply returning the fetched item or an error.

Comment: Btw. this counts to the thinks that make programming ugly, you are allowed to wirte the code like I did first but then the error happens somewhere else, is not intuitive, it requires knowledge of the internals working, etc.

Comment: And also, I'm writing a client library for an API to be consumed, imagine simply offering a function getListOfBooks(), passing the Retrofit result and letting each library user needing to check all the possible nulls and figuring out where in the response is the real data they are waiting for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `response.body()` to a variable and then check for its nulability:

```kotlin
val body = response.body()
if (response.isSuccessful && body != null) {
    val result = body.result
}
```